# inheritance class fraction/integer

Tags: java, inheritance, runtime-error

So, I created a simple class named Test, as follows:

```
import prog.utili.IntegerB;
//It's a custom class
class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      IntegerB a = new IntegerB(1);
      IntegerB b = new IntegerB(2);
      IntegerB sum = a.plus(b);
      System.out.println(sum);
   }
}
```

I wanted to practise with inheritance so I created two custom classes. Fraction...

```
package prog.utili;
public class Fraction
{
   private int num;
   private int den;

   public Fraction(int x, int y)
   {
      [...]
   }

   public Fraction(int x)
   {
      this(x, 1);
   }

   public Fraction plus(Fraction f)
   {
      int n = this.num * f.den + this.den * f.num;
      int d = this.den * f.den;
      return new Fraction(n, d);
   }

   [...]
}
```

...and IntegerB:

```
package prog.utili;
public class IntegerB extends Fraction
{
   public IntegerB(int num)
   {
      super(num);
   }

   public IntegerB plus(IntegerB other)
   {
      return (IntegerB)this.plus(other);
   }
}
```

The problem is I keep getting the same error:

```
at prog.utili.IntegerB.plus(IntegerB.java:11)
```

I know I could simply solve the problem by just deleting the last method on IntegerB and replacing the 9th line of Test.java with

```
IntegerB sum = (IntegerB)a.plus(b)
```

but I absolutely want to do it using the inheritance rules over the "plus" method!

Comment: If you actually implemented `IntegerB.plus(IntegerB)` instead of just trying to forward to the other implementation, it'd probably work.

Comment: You don't say _what_ the error is you're getting ... What is it? :-)

Comment: obviously `StackOverflowError`

Comment: @GregKopff The shell prints hundreds of lines equal to that... I can't even read the "java Test" I just wrote.

Comment: @Marco which IDE are you using?

Comment: @jlordo: yeah, I wanted to coax it out of Marco - to implicitly point out that his problem report lacked some detail.

Comment: @GregKopff I thought so and upvoted your comment right away :)

Comment: I just use notepad and command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement the method `plus(IntegerB)`, you call `plus(IntegerB)`, which calls `plus(IntegerB)`, etc. etc. until you get a StackOverflowError.

Provide an actual implementation for your method:

```
return new IntegerB(this.getNum() + other.getNum());
```

or

```
return new IntegerB(super.plus(other).getNum());
```

Also note that replacing the last line of Test.java by

```
IntegerB sum = (IntegerB)a.plus(b);
```

wouldn't work, since the `plus()` method in `Fraction` doesn't return an `IntegerB`, but a Fraction. You would thus get a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `IntegerB.plus` does not override `Fraction.plus`, it overloads it. This is because the argument types are different.  Thus when `IntegerB.plus` calls `this.plus(other)`, it ends up calling itself, which then calls itself, which then calls itself until you get a StackOverflow (thus sending you to stackoverflow : )).

It seems like you want to call `plus(Fraction)` instead of `plus(IntegerB)`. To do that, you can explicitly upcast `other`:

```
return plus((Fraction) other);
```

This cast has no effect other than to tell the compiler that you want to call the version of plus that handles `Fraction`s, even though you know you have an `IntegerB`.

However, this method would not return an `IntegerB`, but just a `Fraction` whose denominator is 1. You could conceivably override `plus` to return an `IntegerB` if the denominator of the result is 1, but that might lead to unexpected situations where `a.plus(b)` is not equal to `b.plus(a)` because one is a `Fraction` while the other is an `IntegerB`. Alternatively, you could return `IntegerB` objects from `Fraction.plus` when possible.